# Iterate over list and sequentially append each element to a set number of new lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to iterate over a list to split it into new lists, with the elements sequentially assigned as shown below, with the first element appended to `List1`, the second appended to `List2`, and so on, then starting again at `List1` for the fifth element, `List2` for the sixth element, and so on.

Existing list:

```
main_list = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'mangoes', 'kiwis', 'grapes', 'watermelon', 'tangerines', 'plums', 'dragonfruit']
```

Here's what I want:

```
list1 = ['apples', 'kiwis', 'plums']
list2 = ['oranges', 'grapes', 'dragonfruit']
list3 = ['bananas', 'watermelon']
list4 = ['mangoes', 'tangerines']
```

I'm sure has been asked elsewhere, but I can't seem to track it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Slice* the list to get the desired results for each target:

```
list1 = main_list[::4]
list2 = main_list[1::4]
list3 = main_list[2::4]
list4 = main_list[3::4]
```

Answer (score 2):

For something a little more dynamic and supports an n-number of lists, you can use `itertools.cycle`

```
main_list = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'mangoes', 'kiwis', 'grapes', 'watermelon', 'tangerines', 'plums',
             'dragonfruit']

number_of_lists = 4
lists = [[] for _ in range(number_of_lists)]
cycler = cycle(lists)

for ml in main_list:
    next(cycler).append(ml)

for l in lists:
    print(l)


>>> ['apples', 'kiwis', 'plums']
>>> ['oranges', 'grapes', 'dragonfruit']
>>> ['bananas', 'watermelon']
>>> ['mangoes', 'tangerines']
```